# Does AngularJS have a counterpart to Knockout's with-binding?

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js

In knockout.js you can change the scope (or binding context) using the `with`-binding like so

```
<div data-bind="with: theChoosenCar">
  <p>Engine:</p>
  <p data-bind="text: engine"></p>
</div>
```

Is there something similar in AngularJS?

**Example:** Let's say I've tried adding some simple structure to a Controller like so:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.popups = {};
  $scope.popups.errorWindow = {
    isOpen: false,
    open: function() { ... };
    close: function() { ... };
    errorMessage: { ... }
  };
  ... more popups ...
}
```

Do I have to write these kind of "long" bindings:

```
<div ng-show="popups.errorWindow.isOpen">
  <p>{{popups.errorWindow.errorMessage.title}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you create your own directives as class names, that is not possbile; And by the way, angular eliminates the use of such things, which makes html messy;